# $F_n = \{f\in E\mid \exists x\in[0,1], \text{such that for all } y\in [0,1], |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n|x-y|\}$ closed

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E = C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ endowed with the uniform norm $\|\cdot\|_\infty$ and let
$$F_n = \{f\in E\mid \exists x\in[0,1], \text{such that for all } y\in [0,1], |f(x)-f(y)| \leq n|x-y|\}.$$
How to prove that $F_n$ is closed? I need some hint to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the space E its first-countable (the topology its iduced by the metric), we can characterize the closed set with the set that have this property:
$$F\subset E \;s.t. \forall (a_n)\subset E \;s.t. \exists \lim a_n=a \implies a\in E. $$ Let $(f_k)\subset F_n$ such that $f_k\stackrel{||\cdot||_\infty}{\to}f\in E$. We can associate to each function the point $x$ for which the property of $n$-lipschitz is valid, let $(x_k)$ this sequence. By the compactness of $[0,1]$ we can assume that $x_k\to x\in[0,1]$ (unless extracting a sub-sequence). Now we are done because:
$$|f(x)-f(y)|=|f(x)-f(y)\pm f_k(x_k)\pm f_k(y) |\le$$ $$\le|f(x)-f_k(x_k)|+|f_k(y)-f_k(x_k)|+|f_k(y)-f(y)|\le $$
$$\le 2||f_k-f ||_\infty+n|x_k-y| .$$ Now we just take the limit for $k\to \infty$:$$|f(x)-f(y)|\le\lim 2||f_k-f ||_\infty+n|x_k-y|= n|x-y|$$

Comment: Your idea is excellent but there are some typos in the proof.